# Java = operator

Tags: java, autoboxing

```
Integer n = 5;  
System.out.println(n) // 5!
```

How can i reproduce this behavior in my classes?

Comment: Repoduce *what* behaviour? What's the functional requirement?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't. This is called `Autoboxing`, and it is a special feature of some classes in Java to ease working with classes that represent primitive types like `int`.

Comment: its true you cant fake autoboxing, but you can write code that mimics what that code is likely compiled to. `Integer n = new Integer(5);` can easily be modified for whatever your needs are.

Comment: Autoboxing actually generates something more like `Integer.valueOf(5)`, rather than `new Integer(5)`. This is so some instances can be reused.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what behaviour you want, you either can't, or you need to implement the ‘toString()‘ method to get print(ln) to print out a textual representation of your object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload the assignment operator in Java.

Answer (score 1):

You can't overload operators in Java. The guys at Sun decided they would do it for a few classes, but they won't let you do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator cannot be overloaded in java. You need to look at other languages such as C++. I don't know if you can do it even there for the assignment operator.

Comment: You can overload the assignment operator in C++.